# Export CSV file with Pipe delimiter from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I need to export a file in CSV format with a pipe | delimiter instead of a comma from SharePoint. I have changed my settings locally so the default separator is a pipe symbol. But I have to export the file to Excel and then resave as CSV. This defeats the purpose of automating the report.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way to resolve this issues. Essentially I created a one field report with a concatenation expression using all the columns.

= field!name1.value & "|" & field!name2.value & "|" & field!name3.value

and so forth.